# Print Integer with 2 decimal places in Java

Tags: java, format, number-formatting, output

in my code i use integers multiplied by 100 as decimals (0.1 is 10 etc). Can you help me to format output to show it as decimal?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
int x = 100;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); // Set your desired format here.
System.out.println(df.format(x/100.0));
```

Comment: This is not a valid format for `100` it should print `1.00` as per OP expectations where as it prints `100.00`. There is no point in using this.

Comment: @AmitD I guess the OP's question was not clear when I posted this answer. now I see what OP expects. I edited my answer with a very slight change. (x became x/100.0)

Comment: Hi @BlueBullet will you elaborate the meaning of `OP` as I don't understand for what it is stands for? :)

Comment: @Wolvorin hi wolvorin bro =) I was novice about it in the past just like you. Now I know and use it. OP means "Original Poster" or let's say owner of the post.

Answer (score 12):

I would say to use `0.00` as format:

```
      int myNumber = 10;
      DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); 
      System.out.println(format.format(myNumber));
```

It will print like:

```
      10.00
```

**The advantage here is:**

If you do like:

```
      double myNumber = .1;
      DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); 
      System.out.println(format.format(myNumber));
```

It will print like:

```
      0.10
```

Answer (score 5):

You can printout a decimal encoded as an integer by divising by their factor (as a double)

```
int i = 10; // represents 0.10
System.out.println(i / 100.0);
```

prints

```
0.1
```

If you need to always show two decimal places you can use

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", i / 100.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42800823/744133), using [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), this also works:

```
BigDecimal v = BigDecimal.valueOf(10,2);
System.out.println(v.toString());
System.out.println(v.toPlainString());
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", v));
System.out.printf("%.2f\n",v);
```

Or even your good old [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) will work with [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
System.out.println(df.format(v));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
new DecimalFormat("0.00######");
```

or

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
f.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use double instate of int.
it gives you a output with decimals. 
and then you can divide with 100.

Answer (score 0):

you can use double instate of int.
it gives you a output with decimals.

if you want the number to stand behind the dot. you can use this:

```
**int number=100;
double result;
result=number/(number.length-1);**
```

I hope you can you use this.