# Formatting Integer with a decimal point

Tags: java, formatting, decimal-point

I have an integer value that is read from a PLC device via bluetooth and the first digit represent one decimal place. For example: 100 must be formatted to 10.0. Another examples:

```
500 -> 50.0
491 -> 49.1
455 -> 45.5
```

The following line will make it okay:

```
data11.put("Text2", String.format("%.1f", (float)(mArray[18] & 0xFF | mArray[19] << 8) / 10.0));
```

But... Is there another way to do the same using ***String.format*** without divide by 10.0?

Thank you

Comment: Without dividing? I don't believe so, no. Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990451/print-integer-with-2-decimal-places-in-java).

Comment: Why? What's the problem with dividing?

Comment: Can you give more details of the contents of `myArray`, what you'd want to do might be possible with byte operations perhaps

Comment: You are calculating one tenth of something, so you could multiply by `0.1` instead?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I'm newbie to Java and I was wondering maybe String.format could produce the same result without using any extra operation.

Comment: What’s the datetime tag doing?

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate, but I have not yet found the last time it was asked.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following way?

`x = x.substring(0, x.length() - 1) + "." + x.substring(x.length() - 1);`

Comment: I like it. It won’t give what I think you would want if the number was 0, but this special case can be handled with `if`-`else` if needed.

Answer (score 2):

If your concern is the internal rounding that happens with a float representation, consider using [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Like:

```
BigDecimal v = BigDecimal.valueOf(500,1);
System.out.println(v.toString());
```

or combined as

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(500,1).toString());
```

or maybe you need to use

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(500,1).toPlainString());
```

And to answer your original question directly, even this works:

```
BigDecimal v11 = BigDecimal.valueOf(mArray[18] & 0xFF | mArray[19] << 8,1);
data11.put("Text2", String.format("%.1f", v11));
```

But the real question is if this is all really needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
System.out.println(500*0.1);
System.out.println(491*0.1);
System.out.println(455*0.1);
```

Output

```
50.0                                                                                                                                                                                                  
49.1                                                                                                                                                                                                  
45.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go by integer division and modulo:

```
private static String format(int value) {
    return (value / 10) + "." + Math.abs(value % 10);
}
```

`Math.abs()` can be removed if not using negative numbers:

```
private static String format(int value) {
    return (value / 10) + "." + (value % 10);
}
```

*Obviously the method can be inlined...*